# Static access of Enums in Java?

Tags: java, enums, java-11

I have two enums `AttributesProperty` and `ResourceAttributesMapping` each referencing each other as shown below:

```java
import org.apache.commons.collections.map.HashedMap;
    
    import test.xsd.Attribute;
    
    public enum AttributesProperty {
        
        ACP_RESOURCETYPE(ResourceAttributesMapping.ACCESSCONTROLPOLICY,"resourceType"),
        ACP_RESOURCEID(ResourceAttributesMapping.ACCESSCONTROLPOLICY,"resourceID"),
    .............
    
    private ResourceAttributesMapping resource;
        private String attributeName;
    
        private AttributesProperty(ResourceAttributesMapping resource, String attributeName)
        {
            this.resource = resource;
            this.attributeName = attributeName;
        }
    
    public static Map<ResourceAttributesMapping, List<Attribute>> getResTypeMapForAttrName(List<Attribute> attributesList) {
    
        Map<ResourceAttributesMapping, List<Attribute>> attributeMap = new HashedMap();
        
        List<Attribute> attrList = null;
        List<ResourceAttributesMapping> resTypes = new ArrayList<ResourceAttributesMapping>();
        for (Attribute attr : attributesList) {
            boolean flag = false;
            for (AttributesProperty attrProp : AttributesProperty.values()) {
                if (attr.getName().equals(attrProp.getAttributeName())) {
                    
                        if (attributeMap.get(attrProp.getResourceType()) == null) {
                            
                         .........// Some logic
    }
    
    }
```

**Referenced Enum: ResourceAttributesMapping.java**

This enum as seen in imports statically importing the `AttributesProperty` enum.

```java
import static xsd.enums.AttributesProperty.*;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.collections.map.HashedMap;


public enum ResourceAttributesMapping
{
    
    ACCESSCONTROLPOLICY(1, Arrays.asList(ACP_RESOURCETYPE,ACP_RESOURCEID,............)), 
    
    AE(2, Arrays.asList(AE_RESOURCETYPE,AE_RESOURCEID,...........)),

....

private int resourceType;
    private List<AttributesProperty> attrList;

    private ResourceAttributesMapping(int resourceType, List<AttributesProperty> attrList) {
        this.resourceType = resourceType;
        this.attrList = attrList;
    }

    public int getM2MResourceTypes() {
        return resourceType;
    }
    
    public  List<AttributesProperty> getAttributeList(){
        return attrList;
    }

......// accessor methods
}
```

This code was running succesfully on JDK 8, WildFly 15 but after migrating to JDK 11 WildFly 20, I am getting a `NullPointerException` in the `AttributesProperty` 's enums accessor method:

```java
public static Map<ResourceAttributesMapping, List<Attribute>> getResTypeMapForAttrName(List<Attribute> attributesList) {

    Map<ResourceAttributesMapping, List<Attribute>> attributeMap = new HashedMap();
    
    List<Attribute> attrList = null;
    List<ResourceAttributesMapping> resTypes = new ArrayList<ResourceAttributesMapping>();
    for (Attribute attr : attributesList) {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (AttributesProperty attrProp : AttributesProperty.values()) {
            if (attr.getName().equals(attrProp.getAttributeName())) {
                
                    if (attributeMap.get(attrProp.getResourceType()) == null) {
                        
                     .........// Some logic
```

`attrProp.getResourceType()` is giving `null`.

The test scenario is such that on first iteration of running the accesor methods in the enum it runs successfully, however on second iteration I get the `NullPointerException`.

Is there some change in Enums accessing from JDK 8 to 11?

Or the static access of second enum causing the issue.

Comment: "attrProp.getResourceType() is giving null" - is it _returning_ null or throwing the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @Thomas :’attrProp.getResourceType()’ is returning null

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell what's happening here because you didn't post the implementation of `getResourceType()` and other code is missing as well. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Why would that code throw a `NullPointerException` when `getResourceType()` evaluates to `null`? As far as I can see, the map would just look up `null` and most probably return `null` when there is no `null` key.